# Basic Matlab--how to output a 2D array of how many 1's and 0's

Tags: arrays, matlab

I have a basic question in Matlab. I need input a binary signal and output a 2d array where the first column is the number of appearances in sequence and the second column is which value it is.

For example:

```
>> arr = [0;0;0;1;1;1;0];
>> tokenizeSignal(arr)

ans = 
3   0
3   1
1   0
```

three 0's in a row, then three 1's in a row, then one 0.

Answer (score 2):

What you want is called *run-length encoding*. Here's one way to do it:

```
ind = [true; diff(arr)~=0]; % logical index of values that start runs
len = diff([find(ind); numel(arr)+1]); % run lengths
result = [len arr(ind)]; % build result
```

Comment: Or simpler version maybe : `diff(find([true ; diff(arr)~=0 ; true]))`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple method to accomplish this:

```
% input
arr = [0;0;0;1;1;1;0];

% make sure the input is a column vector (else the concatenation
% to create index won't work)
arr = arr(:);

% create an index that is 1 for the first group of equal values,
% 2 for the second group, etc.
index = 1 + cumsum([0 ; logical(diff(arr))]);

% use grpstats to determine how many of each index there are and
% what the unique value associated with that index is; using
% 'min' to determine unique value is fine since all the elements
% in a given group are equal
[count, value] = grpstats(arr, index, {'numel', 'min'});

% display the answer
disp([count, value])
    3     0
    3     1
    1     0
```